# How to use anchor tag in URL?

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, anchor

I want to load certain part of a page when the page loads.
Like i have a image on the top and a form below. So when my user clicks on the image in previous page the user should see the form directly below and not the image.

What i tried.

```
window.scroll
window.scrollTo
window.scrollBy
Element.scrollintoview
```

None of them worked.

But then i tried with anchor tag and it worked like i tried

```
http://localhost:8080/myproject#anchorId (worked fine)
```

But if i do something like this

```
http://localhost:8080/myproject/test.jsp#anchorId (does not work)
```

Please guide how can i use anchor tag when i have jsp in URL

Comment: so, if you click on that image you want that your view to be scrolled to the form?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
element = document.getElementById("divFirst")
alignWithTop = true;
element.scrollIntoView(alignWithTop);
```

Or you can:

Set a `<base>` tag in your document. All identifier links are also relative to it. If this is true, then you need to change your identifier links from

```
<a href="#name">
```

to

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.requestURI}#name">
```

**See also:**
[Is it recommended to use the `<base>` html tag?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)